# How can I tell VS Code Cpptools' clang-tidy support to use the compile_commands.json generated with CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, clang-tidy

I have an existing cross-compilation build that uses Yocto and CMake. I've added:

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

to CMakeLists.txt to generate compile_commands.json as part of my build. How can I tell VSCode's [clang-tidy support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-code-c-december-2021-update-clang-tidy/) to use this file? Can I do it without having to add the long path for the folder that Yocto and CMake put it into?

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the following in your workspace settings.json file:

```json
"C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.clangTidy.useBuildPath": true
```

The setting's description:

> If `true` and `compileCommands` is set, the `-p=<build-path>` argument is passed to clang-tidy instead of build arguments being passed after `--`. This may not work if environment variables aren't set so that system includes can be found.

From the help message for clang-tidy's `-p` flag:

> ```
> -p <build-path> is used to read a compile command database.
>
>     For example, it can be a CMake build directory in which a file named
>     compile_commands.json exists (use -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
>     CMake option to get this output). When no build path is specified,
>     a search for compile_commands.json will be attempted through all
>     parent paths of the first input file . See:
>     https://clang.llvm.org/docs/HowToSetupToolingForLLVM.html for an
>     example of setting up Clang Tooling on a source tree.
> ```

Somewhat related GitHub issue ticket in the vscode-cpptools repo: [C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.clangTidy.useBuildPath should not add "compile_commands.json" to the -p argument #9273](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9273)

I'm not sure if that will just work for you. If it doesn't try specifying the `-p` flag and build path manually (the path to the directory containing the compile commands JSON file) using the `"C_Cpp.codeAnalysis.clangTidy.args"` VS Code setting.